# Ranking 10^10 random strings

Tags: r, sampling, bioinformatics, randomized-algorithms

I would like to model a biological process that starts from a pool of 10^10+ random strings (a string can be 6-24 letters long; the alphabet contains 20 letters, say A-T) and I want to order those strings by similarity to a fixed "target" string, say "ACDFGAEHIIS" (or at least extract the closest 100,000).
I intend to use an [R function](https://rdrr.io/bioc/Biostrings/man/pairwiseAlignment.html) to calculate a distance score between a random string and the target.
Brute-forcing this is not feasible on a modest machine (say 16-core, 32GB RAM), both because of the huge number of starting strings, and the expense of the distance calculation.
Can you think of any ways to make this in-silico experiment more efficient?
I'm not opposed to the idea of breaking this up and running it on AWS, but curious if there's a more clever approach. Thank you!